# string capture after pattern match

Tags: regex, perl, string-matching

```
my $s = '>P1;MOREWORDS';
if ($s =~ m/^>.{2};.*/) {
    print "jjjjj\n";
    my $or = $s =~ /^>.{2};(.*)/;
}
```

When I try to `print $or`, I get `1`, instead of of `MOREWORDS` 
I am trying to capture using `(.)`, but failing to do so.
It correctly prints `jjjjjj` after the match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Match returns a boolean in scalar context. Force list context to make it return the captured strings:

```
my ($or) = $s =~ /^>.{2};(.*)/;
```

Comment: <br/>
thank you for your reply. Can you please explain, why it requires ().
<br/>
Also, what is this concept called in regex/perl?
<br/>
I tried searching a lot, but couldn't find specifically.

Comment: @DeathMetal: Scalar/list context is a key concept in Perl, not related to regular expressions only. See [Context in perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Context).